# Что такое лимит 1000 строк в БД

Tags: mysql, база-данных

Я не могу понять, что такое лимит 1000 строк в БД это у меня будет в HeidiSql видно 1000 строк или как, или если количество пользователей перевалит в БД за 1001 в Бд не будут записываться значения?

Comment: Вы вырвали из контекста. Дополните вопрос оригиналом того что вы прочли. HeidiSql бесплатная утилита так что не понятно что и где вы прочитали

Comment: Речь идёт о лимите в 1000 строк в HeidiSql (для изменения `Tools > Preferences > Data`)? Лимит это для отображения, чтобы не тянуть всё сразу, он никоим образом не касается добавления новых записей.

Comment: @InDevX то есть лимит видимых строк у меня в программе верно? на запись значений и создания новых пользователей в БД это ни как не влияет?

Comment: @whitetears не влеяет.. да и проверить это просто - либо добавьте больше лимита, либо сделайте count()

Comment: @InDevX благодарю